# Why can I only sort by views for my questions and not my answers?

Tags: discussion, views

I'm curious as to the reasoning behind why, on the Activity tab of my profile, when I select the Questions tab I can see the number of views each question has and I can sort by it, but on the Answers tab I can do neither of these things.

I realize that Answers don't have "views" per se, but I would think that I would be able to sort my answers by the number of views the question they're on has. Maybe this only makes sense for accepted answers.

I know it won't really be able to do anything beyond sating my own curiosity about how many people I've actually helped, but then that's all that sorting by views on the Questions tab does too at least to my eyes. Am I missing some purpose here or is it just not coded because no one cared about it at the time?

Comment: Views are only on questions, so would you be wanting to sort your answers by views on the _question_ they're posted to? Because if you want to sort by views on the _answers_... Well, there aren't "views" on answers.

Comment: I guess that's what I meant. Get a sense of which questions I had helped the most people with, although I guess then you'd get the ambiguity of whether it was my answer or someone else's that was "viewed". Maybe it would only make sense for accepted answers.

Comment: Perhaps add that to your question, so it's clear that's what you're hoping for. :)

Comment: If you want a list of your answers, sorted by views on the corresponding questions, you'll need a SEDE query.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While the profile UI doesn't support sorting your answers by their question views, you can do it [in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/609285/answers-by-question-views):

```sql
SELECT q.Id AS [Post Link]
    ,q.ViewCount
FROM Posts a
INNER JOIN Posts q ON q.Id = a.ParentId
WHERE a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC
```

Comment: As a note to the question OP, be aware that the information in SEDE could be up to a week old. However, for the most part, this should give you the overview you're hoping for. It gets refreshed every Sunday, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks that does exactly what I was looking for (barring the data maybe being old, and thanks for that additional info, but yeah it suffices to sate my curiosity).